# Save dataframe column and update

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, updates

I am trying to save a pandas dataframe column instance. but the instance disappears once I make an update in that column, I can't get access to the old instance anymore.

```
C= DF.loc[:,'10']
print(C)
DF.loc[:,'10'] = None
print(C)
```

In the first print I get the last instance of `DF.loc[:,'10']`, in the second one I get a None column. 
How should I do to save the old instance to use it later? 
Does python make an update on variables of the dataframe even when I already saved it? 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Pandas is not a versioned database. If you want to keep the original data you need to make a deepcopy of your dataframe.

Comment: `C= DF.loc[:,'10'].copy()` should do, I believe

Comment: C= DF.loc[:,'10'].copy() worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, setting a variable actually sets a reference to the variable. Variable names in python are references to the original.

The following code should make a copy of `C` and store in `D`

```
C= DF.loc[:,'10']
print(C)
D= DF.loc[:,'10'].copy()

DF.loc[:,'10'] = None
print(C)
```

Comment: can you please explain the phenomen why does python updates on variables? Thank you

Comment: @echtouka That is because in python setting a variable actually sets a reference to the variable. Variable names in python are references to the original.  I would recommend you to read the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)